# Putnam 1988 - Exercise A.5 - Generalization and solution verification

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification, contest-math

I tried to generalize the question given in 1988 Putnam competition, A.5, as follows:

> Prove that, for all real positive $\alpha$, there exists a *unique* function $f$ from the set $\mathbb{R}^+$ of positive real numbers to $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $$f(f(x)) = \alpha x-f(x) \tag{1}\label{1}.$$

My proof is as follows.

For any positive $\alpha$ we have a linear solution given by $f(x) = kx,$
with $$k=-\frac12 + \frac{\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}2>0.$$

Suppose there is another solution $g(x)$ such that, for some $a_0>0$, $g(a_0) < ka_0$, i.e., $g(a_0) = (k-\varepsilon_0) a_0,$ with $0 < \varepsilon_0 < k$. Two iterations of \eqref{1} (recalling that $\alpha =k^2+k$) yield
\begin{eqnarray}
g(g(g(a_0))) &=& g((k^2+\varepsilon_0)a_0) = g(a_1) =\\
&=&k(k+1)(k-\varepsilon_0)a_0 -(k^2+\varepsilon_0)a_0 =\\
&=&\left(k-\frac{k^2+2k+1}{k^2+\varepsilon_0}\varepsilon_0\right)a_1=\\
&=&(k-\varepsilon_1) a_1.
\end{eqnarray}
Since $\varepsilon_0 < k< 2k$, we have that $$\varepsilon_1>\left(1+\frac{1}{k^2+k}\right)\varepsilon_0.$$
If $\varepsilon_1 > k$ we have found a contradiction, because $g(a_1) < 0$. Otherwise we can proceed further with the iterations, and generate
$$\varepsilon_n >\left(1+\frac{1}{k^2+k}\right) \varepsilon_{n-1}> \cdots > \left(1+\frac{1}{k^2+k}\right)^n \varepsilon_0.$$
Since $\lim_{n\to \infty}\varepsilon_n = +\infty$, for $n$ large enough we obtain $g(a_n) < 0$.

If, on the other hand, we find a $g(x)$ such that, for some $a_0$, we get $g(a_0) > ka_0$, that is $g(a_0) = (k+\varepsilon_0) a_0$ for some $\varepsilon_0>0$, then one iteration of \eqref{1} gives
\begin{eqnarray}
g(g(a_0)) &=& g((k+\varepsilon_0)a_0)= g(a_1)=\\
&=&k(k+1)a_0 - (k+\varepsilon_0)a_0 =\\
&=&\frac{k^2-\varepsilon_0}{k+\varepsilon_0}a_1=\\
&=&\left(k-\frac{k+1}{k+\varepsilon_0}\varepsilon_0\right)a_1<ka_1.
\end{eqnarray}
And therefore we can again proceed as in the first case shown above. $\blacksquare$

Can you check if

1. The problem statement is true, and if
2. my solution is valid?

Comment: I haven't read your solution but it seems that the original problem only asks for $\alpha = 6$. Thus your solution, if correct, should be more general.

Comment: @WhatsUp yes, in that case $k=2$.

Comment: Assuming your calculations of $g^3(a_0)$ and $g^2(a_0)$ are correct, then it is fine.

Comment: @amWhy please do not remove indentations and equation labels.

Comment: Another way of putting the basic idea might be: in general, the $n$th iterate of $f$ on a fixed initial value $a_0$ has formula $f^n(a_0) = C_1 k^n + C_2 k_2^n$ for some constants $C_1, C_2$ where $k_2 = \frac{-1-\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2} < 0$ and $|k_2| > |k|$.  So, if $C_2 \ne 0$ then for some $n$ it must be the case that $f^n(a_0) < 0$ giving a contradiction.  Therefore, $f(a_0) = C_1 k$ and $a_0 = f^0(a_0) = C_1$ so $f(a_0) = k a_0$.

Comment: I removed it, dear dfnu, because your formatting of the equation did not render.  After my edit, it did so.

Comment: @amWhy not really, now it's back to normal because I re-edited it. I would appreciate if you do no longer change it, unless you find some content problem. Thanks for you cooperation.

Comment: You didn't post a fully rendered post; I tried to assist.  Sorry to upset you.  Next time proof read and get it right, so no one feels the urge to assist, and then get lambasted by users like you.  At least I motivated you to edit, so it rendered! and it worked! Cheers! :-)